# Dotted line with a white bachground

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there an elegant way to draw a dotted line with white solid line underneath? The reason I'm asking is that often I'm drawing lots polygons which share some dotted sides. However, I would like to have all lines having the same number of dots regardless of how many times each particular line was drawn. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [dotted]
            (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle
            (1,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So here you can see two squares with a shared side. I would like to avoid the shared side having visibly larger number of dots. Obviously, I want a general solution, i.e. one which still involves drawing the same page twice but without the dots adding up.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you draw the common edge of both paths first and in the same direction, the dots will exactly overlap: `\draw [dotted] (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0) -- cycle (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,1) -- (2,0) -- cycle;`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht doesn't necessarily need to be at the start, just need to the same distance from the last move to, e.g. `(0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle (2,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,1) -- cycle`. But that won't help much in a more complex diagram, either.

Comment: Can you show us what are you trying to achieve? A grid of dotted rectangle might be better to achieve with the `grid` operation. You will need a carefully crafted [`dash pattern`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#tikz/dash:pattern) otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common part between both segments need to be the same distance away from the start of a segment (i.e. the recent [move to](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#sec-14.1)):

```
\draw [dotted] 
  (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle
  (2,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,1) -- cycle;
```

Here, the part `(1,0) -- (1,1)` is at the same place and starts one unit after the recent move to (the `(0,0)` or the `(2,0)` at the start of the line).

But this can get messy real quick with a lot of rectangles but you can just draw every side separatly, every horizontal from left to right and every vertical from bottom to top:

```
\draw [dotted]
  foreach \x in {0, ..., 2} {
    foreach \y in {0, ..., 1} {
      [shift={(\x, \y)}]
        (0,0) --  (1,0) (0,0) --  (0,1)
        (0,1) -- +(1,0) (1,0) -- +(0,1)
    }
  };
```

---

It might be better to just define a [`dash pattern`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#tikz/dash:pattern) that has a phase which adds up nicely to the length of your edge.

Since you're using the length of `1`, i.e. `1cm` in the default [*xyz* coordinate system](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.xyz), you could use

```
dash pattern = on \pgflinewidth off .66667mm-\pgflinewidth,
dash phase   = .5\pgflinewidth
% or:
dash         = on \pgflinewidth off .66667mm-\pgflinewidth phase .5\pgflinewidth
```

which means that the line has one square dot (`on \pgflinewidth`) and the next one starts after 0.66667 mm.

Since the `\pgflinewidth` is not a nice number that fits into the metric coordinate system we subtract the `\pgflinewidth` again which means just `.66667mm` needs to fit into 1 cm (which it does 150 times).
The [`dash phase`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#tikz/dash:phase) is needed so that the dot starts with its center at the start of the path.

Now you can simply use the `rectangle` path operation again (or even your version of specifying the corners):

```
\draw[
  dash pattern=on \pgflinewidth off 1mm-\pgflinewidth,
  dash phase=.5\pgflinewidth
] foreach \x in {0, ..., 2} {
    foreach \y in {0, ..., 1} {
      (\x, \y) rectangle + (1,1)    
    }
  };
```

If you change your coordinate system, you need to adjust this value (or we need to write a special key that does that for you but that is a bit mathy).

This also doesn't scale nicely with the line width since `.66667mm` ignores the line width. So, if your line width approaches this value the space between the dots get smaller. (This is why I'm using `1mm` in the example below because of `thick` is used.)

---

I've also added an example with the [`grid` operation](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#pgf.grid) (which just draws non-overlapping straight lines) – which doesn't look that nice because the pattern doesn't fit the coordinate system but it doesn't draw multiple lines on top of each other. (You can of course use a similar dash setting as above to have it nicely line up again).

The fourth example places rectangles along the path of your grid which makes it very easy for weird *xyz* coordinate systems though it will be a bit work do rotate them so that it will look like a dash pattern.

I've placed all examples in a `\matrix` to make it easier to show them in one diagram.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz[thick]\matrix[row sep=5mm, column sep=5mm]{
\draw [dotted] 
  (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle
  (2,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,1) -- cycle;
&
\draw [dotted]
  foreach \x in {0, ..., 2} {
    foreach \y in {0, ..., 1} {
      [shift={(\x, \y)}]
        (0,0) --  (1,0) (0,0) --  (0,1)
        (0,1) -- +(1,0) (1,0) -- +(0,1)
    }
  };
\\
\draw[
  dash pattern=on \pgflinewidth off 1mm-\pgflinewidth,
  dash phase=.5\pgflinewidth
] foreach \x in {0, ..., 2} {
    foreach \y in {0, ..., 1} {
      (\x, \y) rectangle + (1,1)    
    }
  };
&
\draw [dotted] (0,0) grid (3,2);
\\
\fill[x=(30:.5cm), y=(70:.7777cm)]
  foreach \x in {0, ..., 2} {
    foreach \y in {0, ..., 1} {
      [shift={(\x, \y)}]
      foreach \X in {0, ..., 9} {
        foreach \xy/\yx/\v in {x/y/0, y/x/0, x/y/1, y/x/1} {
          ([shift={(-.5\pgflinewidth,-.5\pgflinewidth)}]xyz cs: \xy=\X/10,\yx=\v)
            rectangle + (\pgflinewidth, \pgflinewidth)
        }
      }
    }
  };
\\};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]